# Vim: Align continous lines with spaces

Tags: c++, coding-style, vi, vim

I would like to indent everything in vim with tabs, except a particular case. For example I have this c++ code(where `<tab>` is a tab character series and `<s>` is a space character series):

```
<tab>if(true &&
<tab><s>true)
<tab>{
<tab><tab>//code here
<tab>}
```

I would like after writing '&&' and press 'o' to jump on the next line and start writing to make vim put a tab and the number of spaces till '(' from the line before.

Is it possible to define this coding style in vim?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the `(N` option for `cinoptions`.  Try `set cinoptions+=(0`.  According to the documentation, this looks like the alignment that you seek.

More information can be found by using help command: `:help cinoptions-values` or looking at the online version of the [help for cinoptions-values](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html#cinoptions-values).

As far as tabs go, you'll want to disable `expandtab` with `:set noexpandtab`, and you'll want to make sure your tabstops, soft tabstops, and shiftwidth are all set accordingly.  As an example, the Linux source code uses a style like you mention above, and I have this in my vimrc:

```
setlocal ts=8 sts=8 sw=8 tw=80

" Don't expand tabs to spaces.
setlocal noexpandtab

" Enable automatic C program indenting.
setlocal cindent

" Don't outdent function return types.
setlocal cinoptions+=t0

" No extra indentation for case labels.
setlocal cinoptions+=:0

" No extra indentation for "public", "protected", "private" labels.
setlocal cinoptions+=g0

" Line up function args.
setlocal cinoptions+=(0

" Setup formatoptions:
"   c - auto-wrap comments to textwidth.
"   r - automatically insert comment leader when pressing <Enter>.
"   o - automatically insert comment leader after 'o' or 'O'.
"   q - allow formatting of comments with 'gq'.
"   l - long lines are not broken in insert mode.
"   n - recognize numbered lists.
"   t - autowrap using textwidth,
setlocal formatoptions=croqlnt
```

Comment: works like charm. thanks a lot. also thanks for the info, I'll read the manual for learning more.

Answer (score 0):

Add following in your .vimrc

```
set tabstop=2
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=2
set smarttab
set linebreak
set smartindent
set cindent
set autoindent
```

This is all you need to roll out awesomeness in vim. :)

Comment: is it just me or this indents with space everywhere?
should i show you my vimrc? also is it possible for it to work with other c++ blocks like while or for?

Comment: The `expandtab` is telling Vim to use spaces instead of tabs; try `noexpandtab` instead. Also, when `cindent` is on, calling `smartindent` has no effect so that call can be removed.

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge: I apparently focused on getting the resultant spacing as John required.

Comment: @kiddorails FWIW, I didn't downvote this answer; it's not a million miles from what the OP wanted but does need tweaking

Comment: No it not just you. He simply copied you his config without even trying to answer your question.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: agreed. I didn't know what `expandtab` was for. But, do know about others. Since OP asked for the indentation settings he needed for his vi, I offered him the indentation settings that perfectly works for me. :)

Comment: +1 I'm going to read the manual for each property. Thanks for your efforts!